# Кроссбраузерность таба для IE

Tags: css3, internet-explorer, css, кроссбраузерность

Ребята не могу понять почему в IE текст этого таба оказываться над кнопками? как это можно исправить помогите начинающему верстальщику.

```
<html>
<head>
<script src='http://plc.com.ua/jquery.js' type='text/javascript'></script>
<style>
body {
background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, right top, from(#2F2727), color-stop(0.25, #1a82f7), color-stop(0.5, #2F2727), color-stop(0.75, #1a82f7), to(#2F2727)); 
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(left, #2F2727, #1a82f7, #2F2727, #1a82f7, #2F2727); 
background: -moz-linear-gradient(left, #2F2727, #1a82f7, #2F2727, #1a82f7, #2F2727); 
background: -ms-linear-gradient(left, #2F2727, #1a82f7, #2F2727, #1a82f7, #2F2727); 
background: -o-linear-gradient(left, #2F2727, #1a82f7, #2F2727, #1a82f7, #2F2727);

background:000;

font-family:verdana, sans-serif;color:#333;font-size:10px;
  margin: 23px;
  padding: 123px;
}

a:active {
  outline:none;

}

:focus {
  -moz-outline-style:none;
}
div.panes div {
    display:none;       
    padding:15px 10px;
    border:1px solid #999;
    border-top:0;
    height:486px;
    font-size:14px;
    background-color:rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5)
}

/* root element for tabs  */
ul.tabs {
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none; font-weight: bold;  
}

/* single tab */

ul.tabs li { 
  float: left;
  margin: 0 -15px 0 0;
  padding: 0;
}

/* link inside the tab. uses a background image */
ul.tabs a { 
  float: left;
  position: relative;
  padding: 0 40px;
  height: 0;
  line-height: 30px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #000;
  border-right: 30px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 30px solid #3D3D3D;
  border-bottom-color: #777\9;
  opacity: .3;
  filter: alpha(opacity=30);
}

.tabs a:active {
    outline:none;       
}

/* when mouse enters the tab move the background image */
.tabs a:hover {
border-bottom-color: #9a00ff;
    color:#fff;

}

.tabs a:hover,
.tabs a:focus { 
border-bottom-color: #9a00ff;
  opacity: 1;
  filter: alpha(opacity=100); text-shadow: 0px 0px 20px white;
}

.tabs a:focus {
  outline: 0;
}

/* active tab uses a class name "current". it's highlight is also done by moving the background image. */
ul.tabs a.current, ul.tabs a.current:hover, ul.tabs li.current a {
    background-position: -652px -62px;      
    color:#fff;
    font-weight: bold;
    border-bottom-color: #9a00ff;

text-shadow: 0px 0px 20px white;

}

/* Different widths for tabs: use a class name: w1, w2, w3 or w2 */

/* width 1 */
ul.tabs a.w1            { background-position: -519px 0; width:134px; }
ul.tabs a.w1:hover  { background-position: -519px -31px; }
ul.tabs a.w1.current { background-position: -519px -62px; }

/* width 2 */
ul.tabs a.w2            { background-position: -366px -0px; width:154px; }
ul.tabs a.w2:hover  { background-position: -366px -31px; }
ul.tabs a.w2.current { background-position: -366px -62px; }

/* width 3 */
ul.tabs a.w3            { background-position: -193px -0px; width:174px; }
ul.tabs a.w3:hover  { background-position: -193px -31px; }
ul.tabs a.w3.current { background-position: -193px -62px; }

/* width 4 */
ul.tabs a.w4            { background-position: -0px -0px; width:194px; }
ul.tabs a.w4:hover  { background-position: -0px -31px; }
ul.tabs a.w4.current { background-position: -0px -62px; }

/* initially all panes are hidden */ 
div.panes div.pane {
    display:none;       
}

</style>

</head>
 <body>
<ul class="tabs"> 
  <li><a href="#">СЕМИНАРЫ</a></li> 
  <li><a href="#">НОВИНКИ</a></li> 
  <li><a href="#">вкладка</a></li> 
  </ul>

  <!-- tab "panes" --> 
  <div class="panes"> 
  <div><h2>Первая вкладка.</h2> 
  <p> 
  Содержимое первой вкладки. 
  </p>   
  </div>

  <!-- 1 -->  
  <div class="les"><h2>Вторая вкладка.</h2> 
  <p> 
  Содержимое второй вкладки.
  </p>  
  </div>

  <!-- 2 --> 
  <div class="les"><h2>Третья вкладка.</h2> 
  <p> 
  Содержимое третьей вкладки.
  </p>  
  </div>

  <!-- 3 -->  
  <div class="les"><h2>Четвертая вкладка.</h2> 
  <p> 
  <p>
  Содержимое четвертой вкладки.
  </p>  
  </div>

<div class="les"><h2>Пятая вкладка.</h2> 
  <p> 
  Содержимое пятой вкладки.
  </p>

  </div>

  </div>

<script>

$(function() {

    $("ul.tabs").tabs("div.panes > div");
});
</script> 
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: @Online World, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вместо

```
<html>
<head>
```

я сделал

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8" />
```

чтоб прошло валидацию.. проблем никаких не вижу в ie9

Comment: точно, все верно! блин так примитивно что аж стыдно за вопрос, не знал что валидатор отвечает за это в IE

Comment: ну.. не понял, что значит "валидатор отвечает за это в IE", но валидатор - первое средство проверки на валидность )) простите за тавтологию. 

и.. кстати.. ГДЕ МОИ ЛАЙКИ? )))

Comment: а что есть валидность? какова цель валидатора в трех словах расскажи, леньки гуглить)) лайки? держи ))